# Are historical questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Should questions about the history of the open source idea or open source projects be on topic? The closest I've seen to one is [How could using code released under CC0 infringe on the author's patents?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/133/why-wasnt-cc0-approved-as-an-open-source-software-license) <sup>1</sup>, originally titled "Why wasn't CC0 approved as an open source software license?", which seemed like a good one. A historical answer isn't necessarily necessary for it, but an answer would have to take into account the arguments regarding potential approval/rejection/withdrawal.

<sup>1 The title has been modified, which may have given it a different tone.</sup>

Answer (score 13):

Yes.

They lend variety to the things we talk about - we have a *lot* of licensing questions so far - and they're directly related to open source.

Comment: Do note the current amount of licensing questions doesn't indicate it's a good thing to have that many licensing questions.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, they should be.

Reasoning behind certain decisions in the past can help people build their knowledge on certain topics, and if it is related to open source and licensing, then I don't see a problem with it.